# Open FontDialog with a specific font highlighted

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

If I open the standard save file dialog, or the open file dialog I can set defaults for the folder and file type.
Is there any way that the Font Dialog can be called with the currently selected font that it opens up with heighted being one of my choosing?  In other words if for some reason I wanted it to open with Lucinda Calligraphy as the highlighted font then that is what it would open up with as its current selection.

Comment: if i understand your question, you need a customize `Open FontDialog` because you can't  highlight the `Lucinda Calligraphy` in the list of `FontFamily` unless the Font is designed as `Bold` or `highlighted`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
      Dim fontDialog1 As FontDialog = New FontDialog;
      fontDialog1.Font = new Font("Lucida Calligraphy", 10.0F)

      If fontDialog1.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
          textBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font
          textBox1.ForeColor = fontDialog1.Color
      End If
  End Sub 'button1_Click
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, Thank you so much.