# preloading values for fontdialog in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a "font button" that opens a fontdialog that allows the users to select the font that they want.  They have the ability to click the "font button" again to select a different font.  How do I load the currently selected font information back into the font dialog so they don't have to select it all again?

My code is

```
FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();  
fd.?????? = 15;  // Load the size that they selected the last time
fd.ShowDialog();
```

What replaces the ?????? to make the FontDialog open with 15 in the size?  fd.Font.Size is output only.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation about the [FontDialog.Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.font?view=netframework-4.8) property? There is an example that shows exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Let's see some code son!  what do you have so far?

Comment: What I am trying to figure out is how to preload the fields before I do the FontDialog.Show() so the current values are displayed.  I did look at the documentation and also the intellisence from VS.  All I can find are the output fields...FontDialog.Font.Size, FontDialog.Font.FontFamily, etc. are all { get; } fields.   I have also googled and can't find anywhere the values are being preset.  Am I overlooking something in the documentation?  If you can provide the specific logic for preloading the size and I will figure out the rest.

Comment: sommmen - I think this comment is rude.  I am asking a very specific question about a very specific item, I am not asking why my program doesn't work.  My question is how to preload the size field of a FontDialog.  If you really want to see code...FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();  fd.????? = 15.  Now fill in the ????? for me.

Comment: @Smith5646 You need to update the `Font` property value. Does `fd.Font = new Font(fd.Font.FontFamily, 15)` the job?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open FontDialog with a specific font highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539669/open-fontdialog-with-a-specific-font-highlighted). The question and answer are written in VB.NET, but the underlying `FontDialog` APIs are the same. Notice in that answer that it is setting the `.Font` property to a `Font` instance before calling `.ShowDialog()`. Presumably you have a `Font` instance you can use or you have enough information to create one. If not, that's another piece of the puzzle you'll need to solve to use `FontDialog` the way you want to.

Comment: I never thought about fd.Font being an actual font object.  This should do what I need.  Thanks.